# insert value from reference file

Tags: shell-script

I have a daily csv file with thousands of rows.
I have been asked to concatenate two columns, then insert a new column when a value in a given column matches a table from another file. Empty values are to be expected.

simplifying the data (column 3 is concatenated):

daily.csv

```
HVDS,1810,HVDS_1810,"match value",xxxxx
HVRS,5230,HVRS_5230,"match value",xxxxx
WPHV,0,WPHV_0000,"no match",xxxxx
```

reference file has two columns, searching $1 and inserting $2 above

ref.csv

```
HVDS_1810,dfTVfsd
HVRS_5230,UtsfeOO
WPHV_4242,BBnnstd
```

Just some ideas needed on where to begin.

Comment: awk: read the ref file and store in an associative array, then read the daily file: if $3 is an array key, append the value to the line and print. Plenty of examples on this site and on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question "no match" should be replaced with values from `ref.csv`. A possible solution is with `awk`:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } FNR==NR { m[$1] = $2; next; } { if ($3 in m) { $4 = "\"" m[$3] "\""; } else { $4 = "\"" "\""; } print; }' ref.csv daily.csv
```

Explanation:
`FNR==NR` is true while the first file is read.
We create array `m` with index first column and value third column.
Then in second block we read second file (because of directive `next` in first block), check if column 3 is index of array `m` and if yes set new column value. If not we set empty value.

Comment: Taliezin, "no match" should eq "". (blank is good)

Comment: @Mickey try new one.

Comment: This worked on my OSX with minor tweaks. I will check out on my Ubuntu box later. Thanks a bunch.